# How to call the Power BI Activity Log API

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-factory

I would like to call the Power BI Activity Log API with data factory each day to download the activity events into a blob store. I thought I'd use a Copy data activity with an HTTP dataset as source to call the REST API. How do I authenticate in the HTTP dataset's linked service? Do I need to register an Azure AD application with Power BI admin rights and refer to it in some way in the linked service?

Comment: You can check the Power Shell options for your purpose. You can go through - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-auditing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at [Service Principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/read-only-apis-service-principal-authentication), it can help you to easily authenticate and access Power BI admin read-only APIs (ActivityEvents API included) without tying you to a particular user account. Its in preview feature as of today, but should be soon out of preview.

Also, for automating the fetching of logs using Azure Data Factory and ingesting it in Azure Blob, you may have a look at this great [article](https://justb.dk/blog/2021/02/extracting-the-power-bi-activity-log-with-data-factory/) which explains in detail, all the steps that will be required to create the pipeline. Should be helpful!